# npm, Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-ios

*React-native, npm, expo.*
IOS simmulator.

I get this error and I'm not sure why..

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at App.js:23.

```
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
in RCTView (at View.js:34)
in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

at node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:155:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
at node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync

- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals

App.js:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';

import MealsNavigator from './navigation/MealsNavigator';

enableScreens();

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  });
};

function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoaded(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }

  return <MealsNavigator />;
}
export default App;
```

MealsNavigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Text } from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';
import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';
import FiltersScreen from '../screens/FiltersScreen';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

const defaultStackNavOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? Colors.primaryColor : ''
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold'
  },
  headerBackTitleStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'open-sans'
  },
  headerTintColor: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'white' : Colors.primaryColor,
  headerTitle: 'A Screen'
};

const MealsNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Categories: {
      screen: CategoriesScreen
    },
    CategoryMeals: {
      screen: CategoryMealsScreen
    },
    MealDetail: MealDetailScreen
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: 'Categories',
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions
  }
);

const FavNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Favorites: FavoritesScreen,
    MealDetail: MealDetailScreen
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: 'Categories',
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions
  }
);

const tabScreenConfig = {
  Meals: {
    screen: MealsNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return (
          <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />
        );
      },
      tabBarColor: Colors.primaryColor,
      tabBarLabel:
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold' }}>Meals</Text>
        ) : (
          'Meals'
        )
    }
  },
  Favorites: {
    screen: FavNavigator,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
        return <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={tabInfo.tintColor} />;
      },
      tabBarColor: Colors.accentColor,
      tabBarLabel:
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
          <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold' }}>Favorites</Text>
        ) : (
          'Favorites'
        )
    }
  }
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
  Platform.OS === 'android'
    ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        shifting: true,
        barStyle: {
          backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor
        }
      })
    : createBottomTabNavigator(tabScreenConfig, {
        tabBarOptions: {
          labelStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'open-sans'
          },
          activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor
        }
      });

const FiltersNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Filters: FiltersScreen
  },
  {
    // navigationOptions: {
    //   drawerLabel: 'Filters!!!!'
    // },
    defaultNavigationOptions: defaultStackNavOptions
  }
);

const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MealsFavs: {
      screen: MealsFavTabNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Meals'
      }
    },
    Filters: FiltersNavigator
  },
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: Colors.accentColor,
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'open-sans-bold'
      }
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React Native, but from glancing at docs, it appears that `expo` doesn't export any component called `AppLoading`. Looking at [these docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading/) it seems you need to replace `import { AppLoading } from 'expo';` with `import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';` (you may need to `npm install expo-app-loading` first)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the import you suggested and tried "npm install expo-app-loading" but it didn't work, then I tried "expo install expo-app-loading" and it worked!

Comment: oops sorry, hadn't noticed the install command was different. Apologies for misleading and well done for noticing!